# Taking the data from one file, altering it, and then rewriting it to a new file using python

Tags: python, file

So I'm somewhat new to python and I am trying to write a program that takes the numerical grades in one file and changes them to letter grades. I am also trying to do this without using "with" or sets. This is what I have so far

```
def main():

    #read the file
    name = "grades.dat"
    file = open(name,'r')

    for line in file:
        read_file_contents = file.readline()
        grade_change(read_file_contents)
    file.close()    
    write_file_name = name + "_out"
    write_file = open(write_file_name, 'w')
    write_file.write(read_file_contents)

    write_file.close()


def grade_change(grade):
    float(grade)
    if grade>90:
        return "A"
    elif grade>80:
        return "B"
    elif grade>70:
        return "C"
    elif grade>60:
        return "D"
    elif grade>0:
        return "F"

main()
```

Comment: You need t read each line, casting to float

Comment: Why are you not using `with`? That's definitely the most Pythonic way of handling files (and many other things)

Answer (score 0):

This will just write out the first line of the input file. You should append to a list with each of the output letter grades and then write out each of these to the out file at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you would need to set `grade = float(grade)` to actually cast grade as a float and reassign grade to the result, the easiest way is to loop over your file object and cast as you pass it to your function then open the output file with and write:

```
name = "grades.dat"
def grade_change(grade):
    if grade > 90:
        return "A"
    elif grade > 80:
        return "B"
    elif grade > 70:
        return "C"
    elif grade > 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

with open(name) as f:
    # pass each grade to your function cast to a float
    changed = (grade_change(float(grde)) for grde in f)

with open(write_file_name, "w") as out:
    # iterate over each grade in changed and write adding a newline char
    for gde in changed:
        out.write("{}\n".format(ged))
```

You can do the same thing without using `with` but using `with` is the idiomatic way to open a file in python.
 I presume if the grade is not from A-E it must be an F so we just need an else.

If your file is actually a single line or lines of data separated by spaces then you need to split into individual elements something like the following, if the delimiter is a comma etc.. then pass a comma to split instead, you will also need to decide if you want each grade on single line or a line of grades :

```
with open(name) as f:
    changed = (grade_change(gde) for line in f for gde in line.split())
```